# Visual Studio 2012 - MSVCR110.dll error

Tags: visual-studio

I have a `Windows 7 Express`, with `Visual Studio 2012`. When I run it I get this message:

`"C:\windows\system32\MSVCR110.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try reinstalling the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support".`

I tried these things:

1. Repairing Visual Studio with installation.
2. Uninstalling and installing again.
3. Installing .Net framework manually.
4. Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable
5. Getting the .dll from a computer with a working Visual Studio 2012.
6. Using a different installation of Visual Studio.

Nothing worked and I have no idea what's the problem.

The two installations that I've used worked on different computers with the same operating system.

Please I need ideas!!

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ceba6360-7331-44a1-9346-633546d7e018/winrnrdll-is-either-not-designed-to-run-on-windows-or-it-contains-an-error

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `Windows 7 Service Pack 1` installed? If Not do that first.

Even after that you have two options:

1. Remove & Reinstall by downloading a *new* copy of [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 **Update 4**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

   Check `System requirements` section carefully it requires `Windows 7 Service Pack 1` installed to work.
2. Reinstall Visual Studio 2012 with [**Update 4**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Comment: This file helped fix the same problem on my pc. It is a shame that the threadstarter will not aknowledge your answer.