# error on install matlab2014b x86 "MSVCR110.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error."

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-2012

I,m trying to install matlab 2014b x86 on my laptop, i install windows 7 professional 32 bit, visual studio 2012 and update 4.

now

in the first step to install matlab 2014b x86, i get this error: "MSVCR110.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error."

after that, installed the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 on my laptop, from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679#

but problem not solved

what can i do?

Comment: Have you tried this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117332/visual-studio-2012-msvcr110-dll-error

Comment: of course, remove & reinstall by downloading a new copy of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. but problem not solved!!!!!  i'm confused

Comment: I am very confused as well... Try using admin privilege,  shut down all anti viral etc, and try install VC again

Comment: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 successfully installed, disable anti virus. i must deliver a program tomorrow. but problem not solved yet.

Comment: Have you ever see this error on install matlab 2014b x86 ??

Answer (score 1):

fortunately this problem have a very simple solution!!
i find that after 3 days being involved with my matlab 2014 b x86!!
3 files caused this problem!

> **MSVCR110.dll   MSVCP110.dll   install.jar**

first of all, download two above-mentioned dlls from some assured site, for example i do that from a persian game site!(you know games are affected by this error so often) , and i take install.jar from some good friend!
since may be you dont have my chance! , i upload all this three files here:

> http://uploadboy.com/zseis8p6jwaa.html

so you can download them!
now, copy iso (or if you have dvd, your dvd!) contents on your hard drive, look carefully in contents too find /bin and /java folders. now:

> copy dll files in : /bin/win32 folder
>
> copy jar file in : /java/jar folder

that it! run , install , and joy it!

Answer (score 0):

this problem have on solution. only on solution:

install matlab 2014b x86. thats it.

the problem => solved

i think that MCR in 2014a x86 dont work correctly.